# Angular Unit Testing - Mocking a REST service call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for an Angular application to test frontend functionality and am trying to generate a way to mock a rest service call for the following scenario:

I have a class defined as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {RestService} from "../../../../../services/rest.service";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-class',
  templateUrl: './example-class.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example-class.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleClass implements OnInit {

  myData: any = [];
  reloadInterval: any;
  constructor(private rest: RestService) {
    this.reloadInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.getData();
    }, 10000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    clearInterval(this.reloadInterval);
  }

  getData() {
    this.rest.call(‘exampleClass’, this.rest.id).subscribe((data: {}) => {
      if (data['rows']) {
        this.myData = data['rows'].reduce((accumulator, currRow)=> accumulator + currRow.value, 0);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I want to specifically test my "getData()" method using Karma/Jasmine unit testing framework.  Here's what I've created:

```
describe('ExampleClassComponent', () => {
  let component: ExampleClass;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleClass>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      declarations: [ ExampleClass ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleClass);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create',
    inject(
      [HttpTestingController],
      (httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

This works.  The component gets created and the test passes.  However, when I try to do the following:

```
it('should test number of elements', ()=>{
    component.getData();
    expect(component.myData.length).toBe(1);
 });
```

This fails.  And it fails because it's trying to call the getData() method with a rest call to a service that's not running.  I want to somehow mock the rest call made in that function.  I've tried creating a MockRestService class in my test class as such:

```
class MockRestService extends RestService {
  myData = [
    {myData: 1}
  ];
  
  call(endpoint: string, params?: Object, data?: any, queryString?: string, isCustomUri?: boolean): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.myData);
  }
}
```

and then modifying my test:

```
  it('should test number of elements', ()=>{
    let mockRestService = new MockRestService(null);
    component = new ExampleClass(mockRestService);
    component.getData();
    expect(component.myData.length).toBe(1);
  });
```

But this doesn't work.  Is it possible to mock the rest call made in getData for the purposes of testing, and if so how?  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need separate `MockRestService` class but can use Jasmine's `spyOn` to mock the `RestService.call` method. This could look as follows.

```
it('should test number of elements', ()=> {

    // given
    const restService = TestBed.inject(RestService);
    const data = {} // define your rest call data
    spyOn(restService, 'call').and.returnValue(of(data));

    // when
    component.getData();

    // then
    expect(component.myData.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks SO much for the help!!

Comment: What is `restData` ?

Comment: @Edgar Quintero: I think there was an error in the sample code and `restData` had to be renamed to `data` to make it clear.