# How to fix - Response is undefined when Testing an Angular Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service where am testing (Unit Test) a function which returns an observable.

```
describe( 'MyTest', () => {

let service: MyService;
let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

beforeEach( () => {
    ....
    service = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', [
        'getData'
    ]);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
        declarations:[ ],
        providers:[ MyService ]

    });

    ....
    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
})
it('Should return expected Data',() => {
    service.getData()
        .subscribe((res) => {
                console.log('Response - : ', res);
                expect(res).toEqual(mockedData);
            }
        );
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(exptectedRequestUrl);
    console.log('req.request.url: ', req.request.url);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(mockedData);
});
})
```

When I use `spyOn` with `and.returnValue( of(mockedData) )`, I get error like:

> ....cannot read undefined for `subscribe`

I Have been searching and trying couple of other options.. but the response remains always undefined. Any hint where am going wrong please?

Comment: HI k.Vincet, you need to mock the return value of the mock service getData call
eg:  mockservice.getData.and.returnValue(of(response)); and then call your test code.
please correct me, if I am wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58988059/2358409

Comment: @Mounica, Thanks. But no this does not help. I mentioned that I already tried this option, but it did not help. Unless you mean something else than just using `..and.retrunValue()`

Comment: @uminder, This does also not help as am testing the service itself and not a component which uses a service instance.