# Angular test for ngOnInit subscribe next error

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I have a NgOnInit function which looks like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  const result = this.authService.authorizeUser().subscribe({
    next: (res) => (this.isAuthorized = res.authorized),
    error: (err) => new alert('You do not have the required AD group'),
  });
  return result;
}
```

Question is, how to write unit tests to cover next and error cases inside it?

Tried to adapt various solutions found here, nothing helped. I am quite new to angular testing so sorry if this question sounds stupid.

Tried this approach, test pass but does not add coverage to those two lines:

```
it('should call auth and return values', async () => {
let mockItem: AuthResponse = {employeeId: 'test', authorized: 
true};
let spy = jest.spyOn(component, "ngOnInit");
component.ngOnInit();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(mockItem).toBeDefined();
});

it('should set isAuthorized to false', () => {
const mockResponse = {employeeId: 'test', authorized: true };
   
authServiceMock.authorizeUser.mockReturnValue(of(mockResponse));
component.ngOnInit();
expect(component.isAuthorized).toBe(false);
```

});

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Unit Testing - Mocking a REST service call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984862/angular-unit-testing-mocking-a-rest-service-call)

Comment: I had tried implementing the same logic, it does not cover the next and error lines.

Comment: It does work for me. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Added test code to the first post

Comment: With the given mock data, the expectation must be `expect(component.isAuthorized).toBeTrue();`. The code coverage tool is accurate, your test case does not cover these lines.